# what is the process of designing LDPC code (binary case) to correct specific number of bits?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, compression

I have two binary vectors x1 and x2 of length n=100 bits, with Hamming distance d(x1,x2)≤10. I want to compress x1 with rate H(x1|x2) and transmitting the compressed version of x1 to decoder while putting x2 as the side information at the decoder. Finally, I want to decompress x1 by considering x2 as the side information.

If I want to do this process by utilizing LDPC codes. How should I design the LDPC code to make sure that it has the capability of correcting t=10 bits at the decoder? Generally, I need to know the steps of designing LDPC codes with the capability of correcting t bits?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but the impressions I have are 1) LDPC-codes are designed to work with high probability rather than guaranteeing the ability to correct a fixed number of bit errors. I do realize that your plan is to feed $x_2$ into the decoder as extrinsic information. 2) It feels to me that your codes will be quite short. In my limited experience the length of LDPC-codes is in the thousands.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thanks for your comment. I agree that this code works with high probability but I think there should be a way to help us understand which code has the capability of correcting our errors right? for example if I know that the difference between the transmitted vector and the received vector is 10 bits (of 100 bits) which LDPC code rate I should pick to be able to correct the received vector?